# how to resolve android exception

Tags: java, android, error-handling, launch

**`Iam getting ClassNotFoundException`**, and it's causing a **`RuntimeException`** during the launch of  my Android application.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.mquran, PID: 15561
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mquran/com.example.mquran.QuranActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mquran.QuranActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~hynbSxiLbBBszkZOGN7mmw==/com.example.mquran-lzohw1JV0FF52fn5hJr6Cg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~hynbSxiLbBBszkZOGN7mmw==/com.example.mquran-lzohw1JV0FF52fn5hJr6Cg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3914)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mquran.QuranActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~hynbSxiLbBBszkZOGN7mmw==/com.example.mquran-lzohw1JV0FF52fn5hJr6Cg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~hynbSxiLbBBszkZOGN7mmw==/com.example.mquran-lzohw1JV0FF52fn5hJr6Cg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:44)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1273)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3901)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135) 
2024-01-02 03:17:22.209 15561-15653 libEGL                  com.example.mquran
```

this is the manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:exported="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:targetApi="34">

        <activity
            android:name=".QuranActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have searched alot to solve this error, editing java class but nothing has worked

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you added the activity in the wrong manifest file, that is in a different source set. Take a look on your packages structure. It's really hard to suggest a solution as the problem source can be more than one.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of debugging I have decided to spell check the namespace then clear the cache and check main activity again and it works I hope this could help others.